# How to pluck a column value in has one association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

I have a Vehicle model which has a `has_one` association with `QrCode`.
I want to pluck a specific column of `qr_code` rather than selecting all the columns and mapping single value

I have tried the following code.

```rb
vehicle = Vehicle.first 
code = vehicle.qr_code.pluck(:value)
```

But this is not a valid query

Following code will have the desired value.

```rb
code = vehicle.qr_code.value
```

But the query build by this code is

```sql
SELECT  "qr_codes".* FROM "qr_codes" WHERE "qr_codes"."codeable_id" = $1 AND "qr_codes"."codeable_type" = $2 LIMIT 1  [["codeable_id", 1], ["codeable_type", "Vehicle"]]
```

This is expensive as it selects all column values and there are few columns in qr_codes table that store huge data.

Following is the code implementation

```rb
class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :qr_code, as: :codeable
end

class QrCode < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :codeable, polymorphic: true
end
```

not expected query:

```sql
SELECT  "qr_codes".* FROM "qr_codes" WHERE "qr_codes"."codeable_id" = $1 AND "qr_codes"."codeable_type" = $2 LIMIT 1  [["codeable_id", 1], ["codeable_type", "Vehicle"]]
```

expected query:

```sql
SELECT  "qr_codes".value FROM "qr_codes" WHERE "qr_codes"."codeable_id" = $1 AND "qr_codes"."codeable_type" = $2 LIMIT 1  [["codeable_id", 1], ["codeable_type", "Vehicle"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use query like below for getting vehicle first record with its qr code's value name

```
Vehicle
      .left_outer_joins(:qr_code)
      .select("vehicles.*, 
              (SELECT qr_codes.value from qr_codes WHERE vehicles.id = qr_codes.codeable_id) as value_name")
      .limit(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have `Vehicle` instance:

```
QrCode.
  where(codeable: vehicle).
  pluck(:value).
  first
```

When you have `vehicle_id` only:

```
Vehicle.
  left_joins(:qr_code).
  where(id: vehicle_id).
  pluck('qr_codes.value').
  first
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your expected query -

`QrCode.where(codeable: Vehicle.first).pluck(:value).first`

Answer (score 0):

This will select only value column in the query.

```
Vehicle.joins(:qr_code).select("qr_codes.value").pluck(:value)
```

For a specific vehicle:

```
Vehicle.where(id: 1).joins(:qr_code).select("qr_codes.value").pluck(:value)
```

Comment: select cannot be used to the instance records. It says 
**NoMethodError: private method `select' called for #<QrCode:0x005606b871d3c8>**